# Search bar implemented with HTML and AJAX, not giving desired result

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

Using this tutorial http://aymeric.gaurat.net/2010/how-to-develop-live-search-textbox-in-ruby-on-rails/ as a guideline I have tried to implement my own search bar which will allow a user to start to write in another user's name and see that user (if in the database) as a drop down selection option.

However, when I run my code and type something in, nothing happens.. I am very new to Ruby, Rails and jquery/ajax, so if it's something obvious I apologise.

Here is my code:

customers_search.html.erb:

```
<form id = "live-search-form" method = get action = "<%= search_customers_path %>">
  <input id="search-box" name = "query" type="text" placeholder="find colleagues" />
</form>
<div id="search-results"></div>
```

my customers controller search method:

```
def search
    @q = "%#{params[:query]}%"

    @customers = Customer.where("first_name LIKE ? or last_name LIKE ? ",@q,@q)
  end
```

and here is my application.js file:

```
var main = new function(){

    $('#search-box').bind("keyup", function(){


        var form = $("#live-search-form"); //gets form wrapping search bar
        var url = "/customers/_search"; //_search action
        var formData = form.serialize(); //gets data in the form
        $.get(url, formData,function(html){  //perform an AJAX get

            $('#search-results').html(html);
        });

    });
}

$(document).ready(main);
```

Am I missing an AJAX plugin or something down those lines? Or is it a problem with my actual search method? How can I fix this?
I was trying to match whatever the user typed to either a customer's :first_name or :last_name.

Thanks guys

I have now stopped nesting my 2 forms and placing them side by side. I have also fixed my 'main' undefined error. Still I am getting no response to my search bar.

Comment: What's happening in the Console tab of your developer tools?

Comment: How does your "search" view look?

Comment: @PraveenKumar I do not know what you mean, how do I check?

Comment: @SCraig Press `F12` and click on `Console`. :)

Comment: @archana it shows up as a text input block with the placeholder. When I type 's' to search for a user I know is in the database, nothing happens.

Comment: @PraveenKumar it is saying 1) SCRIPT5009: 'main' is undefined pages.js (2,3).  2) HTML1517: Invalid nesting. A "<form>" tag should not be placed within another "<form>".

Comment: @SCraig Ah! There's your answer.

Comment: @archana OP's using an invalid HTML, so it prevents it from executing JavaScript. Have a look at the comment above.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Could you please tell me how to fix it? I thought it is defined? I am a true beginner here, I really need to learn :(

Comment: @SCraig I understand. Do not nest form inside another form.

Comment: @PraveenKumar How would I get around that if I need my search bar in the middle of another form, but the main form html belongs to my events controller and my search form is for customers in the customer controller?

Comment: @PraveenKumar  I have stopped the nesting but it is still acting in the same manner, is there something else going on?

Comment: I am not sure.... Let's wait for some time.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I have edited my question